# please review hold on my blocker question

Tags: support, review, on-hold

https://superuser.com/questions/1057348/blocker-setup-to-protect-non-technical-users has been rewritten with objective criteria.

Comment: Your revised question is too broad. It is asking **us** (unpaid volunteers) to do a lot of work for you.

Comment: David, thanks, but your concerns (first too vague, now too detailed) sound a lot like Catch 22. Can you suggest a way to phrase my question that would be acceptable?

Comment: David says it's too broad, not too detailed..

Comment: That's not what Catch-22 is

Comment: Question is still out of scope.  There are better venues for this type of question, Superuser, really isn't it

Answer (score 5):

For the record, when this was in the Reopen Votes queue, I skipped the review, but if somebody held a gun to my head and forced me to choose, I would have hit Leave Closed.

The question is no longer opinion-based, but it definitely is too broad. Defending against Internet malware is a *massive* ordeal - there's an entire industry about it! That's definitely too much to adequately sum up in an answer, even one of the maximum length of 30K characters.

Also, your opening paragraph kind of sounds like you're looking for a software recommendation. Such questions are off-topic because they go out of date quickly. If that part was wordsmithed a bit, that would help a little. Still, though, I don't know if it's possible to look for a total Internet security solution here. You might try [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) **after making sure your question is acceptable there**.

Comment: Amusingly, I asked at SR.SE's chatroom about this. They felt that this seemed like a howto question and if the scope was narrowed and the question rewritten as a software rec, it might be on topic